# I write a lambda function that store data from MQTT client to DynamoDB table . I want to add serial number for each data and I don`t know how to add

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, esp8266

I write a python program in aws lambda function it store data from MQTT client to DynamoDB table but it doesn't stored in order so I want to add a serial number to each items I stored in DynamoDB table so that I can filter it out.

```
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    client = boto3.client('dynamodb')
    
    response = client.put_item(
        TableName = 'esp8266_v2',
        Item = {
                'timestamp': {'S': event['timestamp']},
                'accurrent': {'N': str(event['accurrent'])}
        }
    )
    return 0.
```

so this the code I write . it store timestamp value and correspond accurrent value in the table . but I want to add serial number for those value in oreder

current table looks like this

| timestamp | accurrent |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-08-23 22:00:41 | 8.65 |
| 2023-08-23 22:23:15 | 8.75 |

[DynamoDB Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XiLd.jpg)

I want tale look like this

| timestamp | accurrent | serial number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-08-23 22:00:41 | 8.65 | 1 |
| 2023-08-23 22:23:15 | 8.75 | 2 |
| 2023-08-23 22:03:58 | 8.25 | 3 |

MQTT data from ESP8266

{

"timestamp": "2023-08-23 22:00:41",
"accurrent": 8.65

}

I try this code for adding serial number But it give same serial number for all the items instead of each serial number start from 1,2,3...

```
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client = boto3.client('dynamodb')
    
    # Get the current number of items in the DynamoDB table
    response = client.describe_table(TableName='esp8266_v2')
    item_count = response['Table']['ItemCount']
    
    # Calculate the next serial number
    serial_number = item_count + 1
    
    # Store the MQTT data with the serial number in DynamoDB
    response = client.put_item(
        TableName='esp8266_v2',
        Item={
            'serial_number': {'N': str(serial_number)},
            'timestamp': {'S': event['timestamp']},
            'accurrent': {'N': str(event['accurrent'])}
        }
    )
    
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': f'Serial number {serial_number} added successfully.'
    }
```

the ouput table of this code

| timestamp | accurrent | serial number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-08-23 22:00:41 | 8.65 | 1 |
| 2023-08-23 22:23:15 | 8.75 | 1 |
| 2023-08-23 22:03:58 | 8.25 | 1 |

[DynamoDB Table for above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWGdm.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is an auto-incrementing counter which is difficult to achieve using DynamoDB. You Lambda function is only storing 1 item per invocation, so thats why your serial number is always 1.

What you need to do is have an item stored which holds the current count. Read that item, and increment from there, however at high concurrency rates it can cause collisions, [this blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/implement-resource-counters-with-amazon-dynamodb/) can help you with deciding how to handle that.

It seems that you simply want to maintain order across all of the items inserted, a much easier approach is to use a [ULID](https://github.com/ulid/spec) which provides you with lexicographically sorted unique ids.

Comment: I want to store data in order based on timestamp but it stored data in unorder like new timestamp data stored in between old data. but MQTT publish data in timestamp order.

Comment: how to order the timestamp in DynamoDB table

Comment: DynamoDB only achieves ordering using the sort key. So timestamp must be your sort key for your table. If you need globally sorted order, all of the items would need to share the same partition key. You can create an index to help with that.

Comment: Timestamp is string how to filter it

Comment: It orders lexicographically, so usual string filtering.